# "internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582 throw err"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm getting the following error in the console:
`Error : Cannot find module`.

Here is the full error. What should I do?

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\NodeJsProject\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

Comment: I was facing same problem.. I downgraded webpack-dev-server to 2.5.1 version. Now everything is working fine .

Comment: I solved this by using yarn instead of npm

Comment: This error could also be seen if one uses `nvm run` instead of `npm run`

Comment: I am getting this error while running dist folder `npm run serve:ssr`. Why dist folder is depend upon node_module ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had the same issue when I first tried on node js.
I noticed this issue was happening to me because I had some .js files with same names in different directories, which were in the same main directory.
I created another directory outside the main project folder, and created a .js file.
After that, it ran fine.
ex- app.js

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: @Tito In my particular case, I was running a package.json script which was `node 'Server/index.js'` and  should have been `node index.js` instead. I think that's the translation of this answer as well.

Answer (score 212):

**For All => Windows, Linux, Mac**

1. Delete the `node_modules` directory
2. Delete the `package-lock.json` file
3. Run `npm install`
4. Run `npm start`

**For Linux**

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install && npm start
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start

Comment: I acknowledge that this answer has received a lot of upvotes. However, I would rather
strongly suggest being cautious the advice given here. The answers by caseyjustus,
ttfreeman, Bishwajit Vikram, Muhammad Tahir, Andrew Koper all have in common 
that the error in the question shows up when `node` is called on _a file that is 
actually not there_.(!) -- Reinstalling `Node.js` should only be done as a last resort - 
when everything else has failed. You might save yourself some trouble by first 
reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800#62740853).

Comment: @HenkeMaybe answer changed, but it reinstalls dependencies - not node,js

Comment: The essense of this answer is _update everything_. In my case trying to run `jsdoc` it was not node_modules, but node itself that was the issue. After `choco upgrade nodejs` lifted me from node version 13.0.1 to 19.6.0 - JSDoc started working.

Comment: Yeah @Henke was right - I was in the wrong directory. So the file was not there. Once I switched to the right directory, it worked. Duh. On the other hand - it would be good if NodeJs just said "file not found!", instead of this serious sounding error!

Comment: I cannot delete the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` files since they are in a shared directory (google drive) which would affect other devices using them...

Comment: That's not work for me, sir. I've been remove my node modules and package.json and then re-install npm again. But everything was the same

Comment: After completing the above steps, duplicate the .env.example(if present else create new) file and rename it to .env

Answer (score 28):

try the following command

remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

then run the following command to install dependencies

```
npm install
```

finally, run your package by the following command.

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 9):

What helped me was to place the `.js` file that I was working with in a new folder, drag and drop that folder into VS Code (to open the directory directly in VS Code), open the terminal in VS Code, and then simply type `node <filename>.js` (or in my case `node index.js`).

I had already installed `node` on my system, but for whatever reason, I was still getting the error that you've mentioned, even when I typed the direct path to the file i.e. `node /desktop/index.js`.

So, creating a new folder on my desktop, placing the `.js` file inside that folder, opening that folder within VS Code, and then typing `node index.js` in the terminal solved my issue.

Answer (score 8):

#### 1. Read the error message!

Read the error message.
The first line of the second part says :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\NodeJsProject\app.js'
```

So the first thing to check is: *does the file exist?*

On Windows, open a command prompt
(<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `cmd`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Run :

```
dir C:\Users\User\Desktop\NodeJsProject\app.js
```

If the response is – *The system cannot find the path specified.*
– ***or*** – *File Not Found* –
then you know that ***the file doesn't exist***.

---

Likewise, on Linux/Unix (in my case [MSYS2 on Windows](https://www.msys2.org)), run

```
$ ls "C:\Users\User\Desktop\NodeJsProject\app.js"
ls: cannot access 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\NodeJsProject\app.js': No such file or directory
```

Thus, if on Linux you get *No such file or directory*, then you know
that ***the file doesn't exist***.

#### 2. Try running `npm install`

If Section 1 above didn't solve your problem, try running
`npm install`, then `npm start`.

#### 3. Last resort: try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54938249)

If none of the above solved your problem, my last tip is to :

1. delete the `node_modules` directory,
2. delete the `package-lock.json` file,
3. run `npm install`,
4. run `npm start`.

#### 4. If the error happens in VS Code

*Note*: 
The error might occur for no apparent reason when debugging
in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download). 
If you get the error inside VS Code, see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54964538)
helps.

#### 5. How to [reproduce your error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Presumably, you've already installed Node.js on your computer. 
If not, [download](https://nodejs.org/en/download) and install.

The error message is easy to reproduce.
After installing Node.js, open a command line, and run :

```
$ node thisFileDoesNotExist.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\thisFileDoesNotExist.js'
[90m    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)[39m
[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)[39m
[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.14.2
```

#### 6. How to run `node <someFile.js>` *without* an error

To run Node.js in the terminal *without* an error,
in the Windows command line, run :

```
echo console.log('\nHello world!')> hello.js
node hello.js
```

In a Linux terminal, try:

```
echo "console.log('\nHello world\!\n')"> hello.js
node hello.js
```

In both cases, expect the response to be :

```
Hello world!
```

If you delete `hello.js`, and then run `node hello.js`, you should
once again get the error you asked about.

### References

- [MSYS2 | download page](https://www.msys2.org)
- [The most drastic solution to resolve the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54938249)
- [Visual Studio Code | download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download)
- [Answer on what to do if the error happens in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54964538)
- [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- [Node.js | download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download)

Comment: for windows: node_modules location: `%appdata%\npm\node_modules`

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same error because I had a space at the end of my filename(not the reference but the actual filename).  Once I changed 'app.js ' to 'app.js' it worked fine.

Comment: I had the same issue, whitespace in the file's name :)

Answer (score 6):

Replace your file name in `package.json` (`{"npm": <your server code file name>.js}`) with that file where your server code  is running (it should be `app.js`, `main.js`, `start.js`, `server.js`, or whatever you picked up).

Answer (score 6):

For those who are using `TypeScript`, it's caused by `incremental` option in the `compilerOptions` of your settings.

This causes to build `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` file which stores all the data for cache. If you remove that file and recompile the project it should work straight away.

Answer (score 5):

The particular .js file was in the sub folder (/src) of the application and Terminal was in general App folder.(which contains all package files,modules,public folder,src folder) it was throwing that error.Going to (/src) of application resolved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into a similar issue with nodemon running through docker,

it'd be worth checking that your "main" file in your package.json is configured to point at the correct entry point

in package.json

```
"main": "server.js",
"scripts": {
    "start":"nodemon src/server.js",
    "docker:build": "docker build -f ./docker/Dockerfile . "
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you give the right address path for `app.js` when running `node <path>/app.js`. It can't find it

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\NodeJsProject\app.js'
```

Answer (score 4):

It's possible you are not running the terminal command from the right directory.

If you have created a new folder for example, consider navigating into the folder, then run the command from there.

Comment: You are right. My folder was named as rf&ra and  because of this sign & it doesn't worked. I renamed it to rf-ra and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

When I was using the below command, I too was getting the same error:

```
node .function-hello.js
```

I changed my command to below command, it worked fine:

```
node .\function-hello.js
```

Answer (score 3):

The path to the js file you're trying to execute is wrong; you have to type the path and the file name you want to execute relative to root where node is, but what you typed isn't where it is.

I typed `node redux-basics.js`, got this slightly-misleading error message, Stack Overflow'ed, looked at my file system, and I should have typed `node src/redux-basics.js`.

Answer (score 2):

Something weird happened to me last night. 
I ran command `node run watch` instead of `npm run watch`. 
I tried doing everything on this thread but nothing worked out for me. I was frustrated but eventually noticed that I ran the command wrong. I was laughing out loud. Sometimes this things happened. Enjoying learning Nodejs though.

Answer (score 2):

I changed name of my Project's folder and It's worked , i don't know why :)

Comment: I happened to me, but I believe is the name of the parent folder confuses npm because of special characters should it have.

Answer (score 2):

For me "npm install" again from command prompt worked. Command Prompt must be "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 2):

Create the .js file inside the main directory not inside the sub folders such as public or src.

Answer (score 2):

Simply type "*node NodeJsProject/app.js*"

Your program will run :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to your package.json file and check this line:

`"main": "main.js`

File provided in " brackets must be exactly the file you are trying to run with

`node main.js`

This solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

I've got this same issue when working in typescript with nestjs.
For whatever reason after trying to run debugging in VS Code for the first time (with launch.json - which didn't work btw.)

What worked for me was:
**remove dist folder** (the one with generated .js files from .ts files, path to this folder is usually specified in tsconfig.json).

Simple solution, but worked magic :)

Answer (score 2):

i accidentally moved a file outside of /src, that changed the structure of the resultant /build directory, so now in package.json ...    `"dev:serve": "nodemon --inspect=4899 build/index.js",`   didnt exist... it was now in build/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

same happen to me i just resolved by deleting "dist" file and re run the app.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the Node package I was trying to use would only work on an older version of Node.

I was able to fix it by using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install an older version of Node:

```
brew unlink node
brew install node@12
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@12/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

In the above commands, you will need to edit the Node version and then export PATH command.

Answer (score 1):

The below commands resolved the issue for me.

```
npm install node-gyp -g
npm install bcrypt -g

npm install bcrypt -save
```

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled `puppeteer, mocha and chai` using

```
npm uninstall puppeteer mocha chai
```

from the command line and then reinstalled
using

```
npm install puppeteer mocha chai
```

and the error message simply never showed up

Comment: it's really helped to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error:

```
 nodemon -w server.js server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] reading config .\nodemon.json
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] or send SIGHUP to 19248 to restart
[nodemon] ignoring: .\node_modules/**/* .\.next/**/*
[nodemon] watching dir(s): server.js
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js index.js`
[nodemon] forking
[nodemon] child pid: 18840
[nodemon] watching 30 files
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Programming\01a.nextjs\project\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I followed all the advises from here, but none of them worked for me. 
What I found is that I moved the server.js in his own folder server/server.js, but in package.json I forgot to make the change from this:

```
 "dev": "nodemon -w server.js server.js",
 "build": "next build",
 "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
```

to this:

```
"dev": "nodemon -w server/server.js server/server.js",
"build": "next build",
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node server/server.js"
```

After I made this change and restart the server with `npm run dev` everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

you need start server use follow command

```
npm start
```

or

```
yarn start
```

Comment: It was a oops things. I was running node start instead of npn start. Too stupid!

Answer (score 1):

it finally worked for me after I did   sudo npm i cjs-loader (and make sure to install express, not just express-http-proxy)

Answer (score 1):

if you're working with node/express consider running this in your terminal

```
npm i cjs-loader
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I just installed the package and it worked:

```
yarn add cjs-loader --save
```

or

```
npm i cjs-loader --save
```

But notice that sometimes the problem is not only in the absence of this lib, but the path of your application file `app.js` may not be inside this folder:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\NodeJsProject\
```

Answer (score 1):

It ran with me after repairing the node.js installation from the add/remove programs.

This was globally, not for only one project!

Answer (score 1):

For me my problem was with my `Procfile`. I had

```
web: node src/index.js
```

When I should have had:

```
web: node dist/index.js
```

Answer (score 1):

**Remix** users should follow these steps:

Delete the `node_modules` directory
Delete the `package-lock.json` file
Run `npm install`
Run `npm start`
Duplicate the `.env.example` file and rename it to `.env`

Answer (score 0):

Caseyjustus comment helped me.
Apparently I had space in my require path.

```
const listingController = require("../controllers/ listingController");
```

I changed my code to

```
const listingController = require("../controllers/listingController");
```

and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

While tinkering with node 14 and trying to get both CJS and MJS to work I managed to add a package.json file in my `server` directory with

```
{ type: "module" }
```

I forgot I added this file and this was a cause of several wasted hours of looking at this error. Maybe this will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

I placed my server.js (Whatever in your case) file in the wrong directory XD

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using `ts-node` instaed of `tsc && node`

Answer (score 0):

First delete/remove node_modules file, then run this code:

> npm cache clean -force

> npm install -force

> npm start

I hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

My error shown was :
*Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\joel.sebastian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\lib\main.js'........{
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}*

and what went wrong was azure function tools installation and I install that by :
**npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true**
if again showing error of files exists, add force:
**npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true --force**

Answer (score 0):

Usually for me this is because of azure function tools module

> Debugger attached.
> Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
> throw err;

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\lib\main.js'

So for you find the missing module mentioned in the last line and either install or update it

Answer (score 0):

for me, moving my working directory to the location where node was located, solved the issue.

my node location- `C:\Users\hp`

my past working directory location- `D:/Devslane/mywebsocket`

my new working directory path- `C:\Users\hp`

Then open the directory from new location, delete present `node modules`, `package-lock.json` and 'npm install' them again.

Now run `node <filename>.js` and boom!

Answer (score 0):

After creation of custom lib from the official documentation

```
nest g library my-library
```

AND even running

```
npm run prebuild
```

I was always getting the same error because of the files ("libs" dir) outside of src that were being compiled.

[image]

Here was my dist folder:

[image]

I solved with adding "libs" for excluded files in tsconfig.build.ts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might be an another reason apart from above answers so I share this answer since it might help.

In my case my initial project path was `F:\Tutorials\Node & Links\node-and-links-fe`.

> Node allows many ways to require a file (for example, with a relative path or a pre-configured path), before we can load the content of a file into the memory node need to find the absolute location of that file.

> When we require a module, without specifying a path, Node will look for that module in all the **paths** specified by **module.paths** — in order.

> **The paths list is basically a list of node_modules directories under every directory from the current directory to the root directory.**

> **If Node can’t find that module/file in any of these paths, it will throw a “cannot find module error.”**

In my case, With the **'&'** special character in the project path, npm couldn't find the node_module path correctly since it effected to the generated absolute path it confuses npm when find the module.

So I change my project folder name removing '&' and as `F:\Tutorials\Node and Links\node-and-links-fe`.
Then this issue was solved.

You can get better understanding on how npm works under the hood in this reference.
[Requiring modules in Node.js: Everything you need to know](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8/)

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered from this error but the solution was the simple I was running the node app on the different directory than the main where was the app.js was located so I'll suggest you to check the path.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If none of this worked for you, like even deleting and reinstalling npm_modules, like, for me what did the job was:

```
 npm audit fix --force
```

Should(mp) fix the problems and reduce vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was incorrectly running the command (like an eejit):

**I was running:**
`npx run cypress`

**I should have ran:**
`npx cypress run`