# JavaScript Function Not Logging Anything to the Terminal in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, function, terminal, visual-studio-code

I've tried to run the function this way:

```
function helloWorld() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
}

helloWorld()
```

[image]

And I've tried to run the function this way:

```
function helloWorld() {
    let text = "Hello World!";
    console.log(text);
}

helloWorld()
```

[image]

But either way, nothing is getting logged to the terminal. The first way is giving me a syntax error:

`syntax error near unexpected token 'helloWorld'`

Can anyone please help me understand why I'm not able to run a simple function in the terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Thank you

**EDIT**: Added `helloWorld()` to the bottom of the file.

The file is sitting on my desktop. I tried to enter:

`myName-MBP:~ myName$ node </desktop/index.js>`

and this returned:

`bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'`

[image]

**EDIT 2**: The problem was initially solved, but then I started getting this error when running `node` commands:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\NodeJsProject\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

As is described in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800/internal-modules-cjs-loader-js582-throw-err/54964538#54964538). I already had `node` installed on my system.

And what helped me to fix that issue ^ was to create a new folder on my desktop, place the .js file inside of that folder, open that folder within VS Code, and then type `node index.js` in the terminal.

Comment: Have you tried clicking over to the "Output" tab?

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes I can't type anything there - it says "cannot edit in read-only editor"

Comment: No, I meant after you execute the function from the terminal, switch over to the Output to see if it appears there.

Comment: Gotcha - no unfortunately there's nothing there after switching over.

Comment: According to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal), you wouldn't use the terminal to execute code in a separate file. You could enter the function into the terminal and then execute it, just like the browsers Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [arfat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54963577/8550747) states, you can run the code with Node.js in the terminal: `$ node /desktop/index.js`.

Alternatively, you could install the vscode extension [Code Runner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54963577/8550747). This makes it easy to see console logs in the `OUTPUT` tab with a keyboard shortcut: `Ctrl+Alt+N`.

Comment: `node </desktop/index.js>` is still giving me `bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'`

Comment: As Jonas Wilms stated, remove the angle brackets: `node /desktop/index.js`

Answer (score 3):

Do you have `nodejs` installed? If yes, then you can type `node <filepath>` where `filepath` is a path to your file and execute the JavaScript file.

Let's say if your file is called `script.js` then try typing `node script.js` to the terminal and see if that helps. Also, make sure your shell is in the current directory.

JavaScript cannot be executed directly in the bash shell. You need `nodejs` to execute it.

Comment: Even then nothing would get logged, as `helloWorld()` would have to be added to the code itself

Comment: At the bottom of the file (for example line 19), type `helloWorld()`. Right now you are only declaring a function. You need to call it too. Otherwise the function will not be executed.

Comment: Okay I've added `helloWorld()` to the bottom of the file. The file is called `index.js` and it's sitting on my desktop. Then when I try `myName-MBP:~ myNamef$ node </desktop/index.js>` I get:
`bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'`

Comment: The `<...>` means that you don't have to type whats in the brackets, but replace it with a value. Do `node /desktop/index.js`