# Error: Cannot find module running node js and express.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, mongodb, express

I am getting this error and I am attaching a picture

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

> Error: Cannot find module

[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Post CODE. Not PICTURES of CODE

Comment: Likely dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800/internal-modules-cjs-loader-js582-throw-err

Comment: I don't disagree with posting codes but I think the picture attached here did help to pin point the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your console, type in `cd routes`

After that type `node app.js`

You are in the wrong directory

Personal Opinion: 
Usually the `app.js` is not inside the `routes` folder?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping..issue has been resolved..from whole day was stuck in this.