# How to run node in VSCode properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

```
$ node test.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^
```

I tried all the ways (adding/checking PATH route for node js, restarting, using another files etc) and couldn't find why my node doesn't run properly. When I'm typing node -v it returns me version, so it is installed, I go to VSCode and open my any folder. Then in JS file when I'm typing for instance node app.js it throws me error that I wrote above.
Any idea what should I try else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800/internal-modules-cjs-loader-js582-throw-err

Answer (score -2):

Seems like node modules are not properly installed.
Try these steps and let me know:

- delete `node_modules`
- delete `package-lock.json` file
- npm install
- npm start

should be good to go.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. But as I mentioned above, I tried reinstall everything necessary for node js but still throws error.