# Extract the price only from api using node-fetch array

Tags: javascript, node.js, map-function, node-fetch

I am sorry for a basic question, I have been trying to extract only the price using node-fetch from API

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://api.binance.us/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=DOGEUSD')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text))
    
    let AvgPrice = text.map(text => text.price);
```

The error I am receiving is

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^
```

Please, any suggestion is greatly appreciated

Comment: This has little to do with the code itself and rather the setup. How are you running this code?

Comment: I am running it on node. The issue is only in this part (let AvgPrice = text.map(text => text.price); I am not sure how to use map to extract the prince only from the output {"mins":5,"price":"0.5033"}

Comment: Yes i mean, are you using a package.json and then npm run ... or just node index.js or? Check out this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800/internal-modules-cjs-loader-js582-throw-err

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that you need to check out

1. Errors reagarding cjs/loader.js have little or nothing to do with your code per se but rather the setup, for example how you run the code, naming of the file, etc,

[internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582 throw err](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800/internal-modules-cjs-loader-js582-throw-err)
https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1846

2. This code will return Reference error: text is not defined.

The reason is that you never define the variable text and then you try to call map function on it.

Also fetch is a async function and nodejs is single threaded non-blocking.  So what happens is that you send a http request (fetch) to the website, that takes times, but meanwhile your coding is still running, so continues to the next line in your code.

Lets add some console logs

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

console.log('1. lets start')
fetch('https://api.binance.us/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=DOGEUSD')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => {
      console.log('2. I got my text', text)

    })
console.log('3. Done')
```

You might think that this will log out

1. lets start
2. I got my text {"mins":5,"price":"0.4998"}
3. Done

Nopes, it will log out

1. Lets start
2. Done
3. I got my text {"mins":5,"price":"0.4998"}

Because you fetched the data, then your program continued, it looged out 3. Done and THEN when it got the data from api.binance it logged out 2. I got my text (notice the keyword then, it happens later)

3. map is a function for arrays. What the api returns is an object. So when you fix your async code, you will get TypeError text.map is not a function

Since it returns an object you can access it's property right away `text.price`

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I didnt know that an object, i tried text.price and didnt work. have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, the code I showed is working. res.text() gives a stringified json, so you would need to parse it or use res.json() and not res.text()