# errorr in node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to run react app I got this error:

```
☁  app [master] yarn start
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-scripts start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/li/Documents/reacts/app/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:416:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:669:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/li/Documents/reacts/app/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parser.js:1:17) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.0.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How do I download the app ?

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

my stuff version

node -v v17.0.1

yarn -v 1.22.17

npm -v 8.1.4

I've tried every single thing in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800/internal-modules-cjs-loader-js582-throw-err) but nothing worked for me

Comment: Seems related to [this issue](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-safe-parser/issues/29).

Comment: @GOTO0 So I have to downgrade the version of node?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error, then I ran `npm update` and that seemed to clear up this error. But now I'm getting a new error about "no such file or directory, stat '/home//.steampath'"

Maybe that's just a separate issue with mine though, hopefully npm update works for you!

Edit: I was able to fix my "no such directory" error, it was caused by an issue with me trying to transfer a file from a different drive. I was able to resolve it. So unless you also have that same problem, `npm update` should fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, as well. I was able to get CRA to work by installing/using Node v16.13.1 via [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). This is an issue with CRA depending on an old version of postcss-safe-parser referenced [here](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-safe-parser/issues/29).

First install NVM and then ...

```
nvm install 16
```

Make sure node 16 is being used by NVM and `yarn start` should work.