# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078 throw err; ^

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am having this error in windows 10 with npm  run command
:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063
 throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\mobile-version portfolio\
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1060:15)
at node:internal/main/check_syntax:34:20 {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
}
```

Node.js v19.6.0   someone help me please.

I have uninstalled and installed node.js, but didn't work for me, I also deleted node-modules and installed again but all is not working.

When I try to run any npm command i.e npm run start, npm run build or check linter errors with npx stylelint `**/*.{css,scss}` it throws the same error.am working with webpack and I need to run the command to update my changes in dist file from src file.

I also need to run and check linter errors and fix in my project. Here is my `package.json` file:

```
 "name": "to-do-list",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "README.md\r One attachment\r • Scanned by Gmail\r <a name=\"readme-top\"></a>",
 "main": "index.js",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "start": "webpack serve --open",
   "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
 },


 "repository": {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "git+https://github.com/Tracy-miranja/TO-DO-LIST.git"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "bugs": {
   "url": "https://github.com/Tracy-miranja/TO-DO-LIST/issues"
 },


 "homepage": "https://github.com/Tracy-miranja/TO-DO-LIST#readme",
 "devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
   "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
   "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
   "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
   "eslint": "^7.32.0",
   "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
   "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
   "hint": "^2.0.0",
   "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
   "sass": "^1.49.9",
   "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
   "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
   "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
   "stylelint-config-standard": "^21.0.0",
   "stylelint-csstree-validator": "^1.9.0",
   "stylelint-scss": "^3.21.0",
   "webpack": "^5.75.0",
   "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0",
   "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
 },


 "dependencies": {
   "lodash": "^4.17.21"
 }
}
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: The error message says "Cannot find module D:\mobile-version portfolio\".
It probably wants one or more *files*, but you're giving it a *directory*.
What's inside of that directory? Any CSS files?
~ * ~
Recommended reading: [Read the error message!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740853)

Answer (score 3):

You are just opening the terminal in the wrong folder.

The index file is inside the BestMe folder:
`~/Desktop/Programação/Rocketseat/Discover/NodeJS/BestMe`

##### The First Way

[image: The first way]

##### The Second Way

[image: The second way]

Answer (score 0):

using this command :
1  npm i -f
2  npm update -f
3  npm audit fix -f
npm relaced by npx  =>
4  npx nodemon
if you not install nodemon then firstly install nodemon using this command :
5  npm i nodemon --force
6  npx nodemon

{
thankyou enjoy yor journey
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Installing `stylelint` globally 'worked' for me. `npm i -g stylelint@version`
You can try it till a better solution is given.

Answer (score -1):

check for extension, I had faced same problem, which was because of index,js name of the file,
which should have been index.js instead.
Silly mistake, I know.

Answer (score -1):

if you're trying to require a JavaScript file, make sure you include the file extension (e.g., require('filename.js')) and then open terminal. Type tsc and then type node filename.

Answer (score -2):

If you are following course 'The Complete 2023 Web Development Bootcamp by dr angela yu' and getting an error like:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
throw err;
then you have not followed all steps correctly.
I forgot to remove the line 'const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");'
so I was getting an error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlJsO.png)